# Return generic type of type alias

Tags: javascript, typescript

I Have A Type with two generic parameters

```js
type FirstLevelType<A, Z> = {
  _: "typeCheck";
};
```

But I Need Wrap this type with another

```js
type TestWrapperType<T, U> = FirstLevelType<T, U>;
```

After I have create variable with TestWrapperType, I need to get generic parameters.

```js
const a: TestWrapperType<{ cat: string }, { dog: number }> = {
  _: "typeCheck",
};
```

But I can use only FirstLevelType to prevent growing code length, because wrapper types can be created many times.

```js
type ExtendFirst = typeof a extends FirstLevelType<infer T, infer U>
  ? T
  : "not extended";
```

Resulted type = unknown

Excepted type = {cat: string}

```js
type ExtendWrapper = typeof a extends TestWrapperType<infer T, infer U>
  ? T
  : "not extended";
```

Resulted type = {cat: string}

Excepted type = {cat: string}

Why ExtendFirst type is unknown? And how can I solve this issue.

[Update 1]

If FirstLevelType declared as interface, when Resulted Type will be correct. However, when my wrapper has other properties, resulted type unknow again.

```js
type TestWrapperType<T, U> = FirstLevelType<T, U> & {
  seal?: boolean;
};
```

Comment: What other properties do you mean? Please provide an example with other properties

Comment: Is there a reason why `FirstLevelType<A,Z>` has no structural dependence on `A` or `Z`?  It’s asking for trouble to do this, since `FirstLevelType<string, number>` is equivalent to `FirstLevelType<boolean, Date>` and therefore inference of type parameters is problem.  I see that you’ve accepted the answer about changing to an interface, but I expect that to be fragile.  It would ge better to add members of types `A` and `Z` to `FirstLevelType<A,Z>` if you want more robust type inference.

Comment: @jcalz These generics used because their do not direct related to object inherited FirstLevelType, but there are used to create dynamically class methods, where A is argument, Z is returning, related key of object `Record<string, FirstLevelType<A,Z>>` is method name.

Comment: But you’re *not* using the parameters; see [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--).

Comment: @jcalz Ok, i see it. But my code work now like a charm. Should I really create unnecessary properties only not to break the rule?

Comment: It’s not so much a “rule” as it is insurance against inference weirdness.  Maybe your code will work fine without it, but maybe someday something will change about either your usage or the compiler implementation that causes a structural check and then the problem will reappear.  You don’t necessarily have to change it if it’s working for you, but you should at least be aware of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it work, just use `interface` for `FirstLevelType` instead of `type`.

```js
// used interface instead of type
interface FirstLevelType<A, Z> {
    _: "typeCheck";
};

type TestWrapperType<T, U> = FirstLevelType<T, U>;


const a: TestWrapperType<{ cat: string }, { dog: number }> = {
  _: "typeCheck",
};

type ExtendFirst = typeof a extends FirstLevelType<infer T, infer _>
    ? T
    : "not extended";


type ExtendWrapper = typeof a extends TestWrapperType<infer T, infer _>
    ? T
    : "not extended";
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLCgZzAGQgNwgBsAVATwAcIAeAQQBpkAtAPmQG8BYAKGT%20QD6ALmQAiMJQgBhABYQEAa1EBuHgF9V3HhKrISEbAHUocClSjkq1EowCqbALxoM2PIVKTrdlpp48EAPYg2MhwIvpGJmbQljTsyAhwYCLYUKAA5shqjPEAJgHpIiAArgC2AEbQWY4cPHzCYjrScoqi9Oq%203E3IAKIAHpAguehYYMhOTQEwocgQAxBDmM6jbsSx1KAwVTbIm1UCLHX8APx6R3wioiABY3ODuRC5Kn5aXZK980PGpubjyJPTOCzT65JYRMDfaIWTx7KB6RiwwSHXgnM4oi5ia63EGPZ6vIA)

I believe this is because interfaces are lazy evaluated when `types` - eagerly.

> If FirstLevelType declared as interface, when Resulted Type will be correct. However, when my wrapper has other properties, resulted type unknow again.

Since your `TestWrapperType` might be extended, you should infer these `rest` props:

```js
type FirstLevelType<A, Z> = {
    _: "typeCheck";
};


type TestWrapperType<T, U> = FirstLevelType<T, U> & {
    seal?: boolean;
}

const a: TestWrapperType<{ cat: string }, { dog: number }> = {
    _: "typeCheck",
};

// { cat: string; }
type ExtendFirst = typeof a extends FirstLevelType<infer T, infer _> & infer RestProps
    ? T
    : "not extended";
```

Now you can use `type` for `FirstLevelType`

Comment: It is correct answer, but do not solve my issue :(
Because my wrappers has own properties.

Comment: What do you mean? COuld you please provide an example?

Comment: I have updated my question, please take a look there.

Comment: If `FirstLevelType<A,Z>` does not structurally depend on its type parameters, then there’s no guarantee that inference of type parameters will work correctly. I think that interfaces being evaluated lazily means that the compiler assumes structural dependence, but I don’t know that it can be relied on.  For best results, there should be members of types `A` and `Z` or of types that depend on them.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for commenting. It works perfectly fine if generic are used. Was not aware about such kind of difference between types and interfaces