# Recurse a generic within Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

Typescript throws an error with the following code:

```js
type AndType<AstT> = { type: 'And', args: [AstT] };
type TrueType = { type: 'True' };
type BaseAST = AndType<BaseAST> | TrueType;
```

Complaining that `Type alias 'BaseAST' circularly references itself.`; however, if I wrap the circular reference in an object, the types compile fine:

```js
type AndType<AstT> = { type: 'And', args: [AstT] };
type TrueType = { type: 'True' };
type BaseAST = {value: AndType<BaseAST>} | {value: TrueType};
```

Why? Does anyone have a reference to the docs where this behavior is defined?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14174 sounds like it's a limitation of type aliases. Someone who knows more than me should give the details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution in your case is to make the `AndType` type an interface as follows:

```
interface AndType<AstT> {
  type: 'And';
  args: [AstT];
}
type TrueType = { type: 'True' };
type BaseAST = AndType<BaseAST> | TrueType;
```

In general it's recommended to use interfaces for straightforward types, but this isn't always possible. The link already given should give you more in-depth information.

Comment: This is because interfaces are lazy evaluated when types - eagerly. See this answer for more context and another one example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68601578/return-generic-type-of-type-alias/68601916#68601916